# how to match a template real time using a camera with opencv and python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am not getting the rectangle on the object to be matched.Can some one tell me whats wrong with my code or can you please  write a better code ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
template = cv2.imread('tnmul.jpg',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    i= cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(i,template,2)
    cv2.imshow('frame',i)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[0] + h)
    cv2.rectangle(i, top_left, bottom_right, (50, 0, 130), 2)
    cv2.imshow('output',i)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What's the result you are getting? Where is the error?

Comment: there is no error in the program!it runs but it does'nt match.I mean it does not  draw a rectangle on the image to be matched .The result is that it just keeps running in the loop without matching

Answer (score 0):

Since you have passed 2 as argument in the function matchTemplate that implies you are using normalized square difference(CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) for similarity computation. Therefore your result would be stored in min_loc. So, instead of this line use

```
top_left = min_loc
```

Cause the minimum value will contain the best match.